# Как правильно вставить header?

Tags: html, css

Есть хедер, и контейнер, хедер во всю ширину контейнера, как сделать чтобы он был над бекграундом нижнего блока, пишу position: absolute, флексы и ширина сбиваются[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position: absolute header ставь. а контенеру position: relative; если ты хочешь таким способом

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.contanier {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Хедер</div>
<div class="contanier">Контейнер</div>
```